# What word or phrase would describe somebody who is under a lot of pressure?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I can't think of a word that describes somebody who is under a lot of pressure. The most satisfactory word I can think of is "strained," but that isn't very rich. It can be an adjective, noun, or even verb, as long as it describes somebody who is under a lot of pressure. I'll tell you if I end up using your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: "Stressed" seems like it would fit here.

Comment: @BradC Hmm, well that isn't a very vivid alternative. Do you have a different, more descriptive adjective?

Comment: Deep sea diver.

Comment: You are supposed to consult common reference sources before posting here. Have you looked at [a thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/stressed)? What did you find? Why didn't you like any of the words?

Comment: Just *pressed* or *hard pressed* (*hard-pressed*): *The juice company was hard pressed to come up with a solution.* I stole that from Forbes.

Comment: Uh, *employee*?

Comment: *under a lot of pressure* = *pressured* [= one word]

Comment: #
 
 
"overburdened"
 
 
 #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say that they're **under the gun**.

> In a stressful situation that requires quick action, often to meet a deadline; under pressure.
> https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/under+the+gun

"Under pressure" (which you've already used in your question) seems to work too.

Comment: Oh, perfect. I've never heard that one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

harried, burdened, under the pump, flat out like a lizard drinking... many options, but depends on your intended tone, context & co.